# Unknown reason for FileNotFoundException

Tags: android, file

I have a method : `copyImage`
thats take two string arguments ( **source** image , **target** image) inside `ImageLoder`class as shown below:

```
public Class ImageLoader{

public boolean copyIMAGE(String source, String target){


        File sourceFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+source);

        File targetFile=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+target);

        InputStream fis;

        OutputStream fos;

        BufferedOutputStream bufferIS;


        try{

            fis=new FileInputStream(destinationFile);
            fos=new FileOutputStream(targetFile);
            bufferIS=new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

            byte[] b=new byte[1024];

            int len=0;


            try
            {
                while ((len = fis.read(b)) != -1)

                {           
                    fos.write(len);

                }

                bufferIS.close();
            fos.close();
            fis.close();
                return true;
            }

            catch (IOException e)
            {

        }


            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){


        }

return false;

    }


}
```

the method fired after copyButton get clicked in MainActivity class and copyImage return false

```
copyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    // TODO: Implement this method


                    String source="/storage/emulated/0/Download/my image.jpeg";

                    String target ="/storage/emulated/0/Download//images/my image.jpeg";

                    loader.copyIMAGE(source,target);

            }   
        });
```

The method return false and i get FileNotFound exception .

**Ps:** the source file exists,
 the destination exist,
i have **rw** permissions.

Comment: For which file is the exception?

Comment: Print the stack traces in your catch blocks.

Comment: I dont know because i use my smartphone ide .for debugging i use Toast messages

Comment: Dont call a source file a destinationFile. Quite confusing.

Comment: You should end with fos.close(). And fis.close() would be nice too.

Comment: I see no Toast() . And of course you should be able to find out.  e.getMessage() will mostly tell you.

Comment: thanks .i did that and the file get copied but it seems that not all bytes get copied the target file is corrupted

Comment: Adapt your code here too please.

Comment: `fos.write(len);` that should be `fos.write(b, 0, len);`.

Comment: thankyou all now my problem has been solved.shoud i put an update in the answer?

Comment: And do not name a buffer b and dont use variable names of one character. Name that buffer buffer.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`? Remove this as `source` and `target` are already full paths.

```
File destinationFile=new File(source);

File targetFile=new File(target);
```

And also your copy function is incorrect, you are calling `write` with wrong parameters.

```
while ((len = fis.read(b)) != -1)

{           
    fos.write(b, 0, len);

}
```

Comment: thanks .i did that and the file get copied but it seems that not all bytes get copied the target file is corrupted